# How to Handle Data Posted From Angular in Laravel

Tags: angularjs, json, laravel

I am trying to update my database with data posted by AgularJs to Laravel, and I can't get laravel to handle data.

**Route**

```php
Route::get('/api/editsubpages/', 'NewSubPagesController@editsubpage');
```

**Laravel Controller**

```php
public function editsubpage(Request $request)
{
    dd(json_decode($request->getContent(), true)); // returns empty array

    // here goes code for updating database
    return response()->json($request->all(), 200);
}
```

**Angular Controller**

```js
$http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: '/api/editsubpages/' ,
    contentType: 'JSON',
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
    processData: false,
    data: $scope.data
}).then(
    function success(response) {
    console.log("error");
},
function failed(response) {
    console.log("error");
});
```

The JSON posted in "Request Payload," but I can't even print it.

Comment: usual `$request->all()` should work. Decoding part will be handled by Laravel itself.

Comment: i've tried that, returns empty array!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i've changed

```
    $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: '/api/editsubpages/' ,
        contentType: 'JSON',
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
        processData: false,
        data: $scope.data
    }).then(
        function success(response) {
            console.log("error");
        },
        function failed(response) {
            console.log("error");
        });
```

To

```
$http.post('/api/editsubpages', {
            data: $scope.data,
        }).then(function mySuccess(response) {

        }, function myError(response) {
            console.log("error");
        });
```

and it's working now! can someone tell me what's the difference? i don't get it!

Comment: im guessing this is due to a different `Content-Type` header. If you really want to know, try both codes in your browser, and use your browser tools Network tab to analyze the requests.

Comment: Nope. Done that, same answer. But somehow in the first situation opens 2 pages in background and i supose there is some data loss in the proces